# Synchronizing Thread for image processing Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, synchronization, delphi-xe3, tthread

I must processing one image in main form , but the processing speed is low for inc speed i use thread...

My thread code :

```
type
  TPaintThread = class(TThread)
    Source,Mask :TBitmap ;
    image : TImage;
    public
       procedure SetAll(src,msk:TBitmap;img:TImage);
    private
     procedure  DoWritePix;
    var
       mBit : TBitmap ;

    protected
      procedure Execute; override;
  end;

implementation

procedure TPaintThread.SetAll(src: TBitmap; msk: TBitmap; img: TImage);
begin
      Source := src ;
      mask := msk ;
      img := img ;
      mBit := TBitmap.Create ;
end;

procedure TPaintThread.DoWritePix;
begin
  image.Picture.Bitmap := mBit ;
end;

procedure TPaintThread.Execute;
var
    i: Integer;
    j: Integer;
begin
  mBit.Width := Source.Width ;
  mBit.Height := Source.Height ;
  for i := 1 to Source.Width do
    for j := 1 to Source.Width do
    begin
      // my processing event
    end;
    // result := mBit ;
    // write on form image 
    Synchronize(DoWritePix);
end;
```

and I'm use it in on `timer` :

```
procedure TForm1.tmr1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
    pThread  : TPaintThread ;
begin
  pThread := TPaintThread.Create(True) ;
  pThread.SetAll(MyBmp,mask,img1);
  pThread.Resume ;
  pThread.FreeOnTerminate := True ;
end;
```

but I have error in `DoWritePix` in run time :

```
First chance exception at $005A81DE. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x005a81de: read of address 0x000001b8'. Process myexe.exe (6032)
First chance exception at $754E9617. Exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 005A81DE in module 'myexe.exe'. Read of address 000001B8'. Process myexe.exe (6032)
```

My question: Is that way correct for edit image in main form or not ? if not what is correct way access and write on thread? if yes how I can solve problem ?

Comment: Set 'FreeOnTerminate' before you resume. The thread may execute and finish before the execution hits setting FreeOnTerminate line. In fact don't use resume at all, refer to documentation for why..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code is wrong:

```
procedure TPaintThread.SetAll(src: TBitmap; msk: TBitmap; img: TImage);
begin
  Source := src ;
  mask := msk ;
  img := img ; // OOPS!
  mBit := TBitmap.Create ;
end;
```

When you write `img := img;` you are doing nothing – that is a no-op. You meant to write:

```
image := img;
```

And that's why `image` is `nil` in `DoWritePix` which explains the access violation.

Don't be helpless when you face a runtime error. Run the code under the debugger and let the debugger tell you which variable is not initialised.